# What is the difference between Object-Graph and a class diagram?

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram, object-graph

Is there a difference in the meaning of "class diagram" and "object graph"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this tutorial 
http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jm/340S/Slides6/ClassD.pdf

Object graph contains value of one **instance** of class see [example View](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aObject_diagram.png) its a view of an object system at a particular point in time

while

class diagram as wiki

```
The class diagram is the main building block of object oriented modelling. It is used both for general conceptual modelling of the systematics of the application, and for detailed modelling translating the models into programming code. Class diagrams can also be used for data modeling.[1] The classes in a class diagram represent both the main objects and or interactions in the application and the objects to be programmed. In the class diagram these classes are represented with boxes which contain three parts: [2]


A class with three sections.
The upper part holds the name of the class
The middle part contains the attributes of the class
The bottom part gives the methods or operations the class can take or undertake
```

see [further](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous post but would like to add that a class diagram is based on UML which is an accredited language sponsored by the OMG and known by over 5 millions users. UML is therefore a standard based on a model  from which you get views.

IN UML 2 the class diagram is fantastic if used with Java because it seems to me that the new specification has exactly the same structure as a java project. It include a project name, with packages including classifiers (e.g. Class, interface, enum) which includes attributes, methodes which includes properties.

If you have to use just one diagram I would say to use Class diagram. It is easy to create because you don't need to know UML and can reverse engineer your project into a model a get class diagram views.  My  class diagram is Just magic:-)

Answer (score 0):

Class diagram represent class name,its attributes and behaviours whereas object diagram represent instance of class diagram,object diagram comes under class diagram